# Erro ao fazer upload da apk no google play console

Tags: android, upload, app, google-play, apk

Estou fazendo o upload do meu app na google play e não estou conseguindo subir meu apk, alguém sabe qual o erro?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas o erro ta escrito ai, vc não pode subir outro apk com a mesma versão, é só mudar pra versão 2 (ou 1.1)

Comment: eu sou novo nisso

Comment: Eu acho q nao subi nada kkkj, ai já não sei.  Como trocaria essa versão ou onde posso ver o apk que já subi?

Comment: Consegui achar o onde fica, de qualquer forma obrigado, seu resposta clareou minha cabeça!

Comment: Vc foi no build.gradle la dentro do /app? E aumentou o versionCode lá?

Comment: Não eu deletei o que tinha subido errado, que foi a versão 1 e depois subi novamente esse versão

Comment: Para não precisar excluir dos seus artefatos, altere `versionCode` no `build.gradle` a nível de aplicativo e `android:versionCode` em `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troquei o versionCode no  build.glade e subi novamente.